# Getting Forward Right Up Vector From Transformation Matrix

Tags: c++, glm-math, bulletphysics, bullet

How can I get a Forward, Right, and Up Vector from a Transformation Matrix?

I want to use these vectors as a basis to apply force to rigid bodies in different directions.

```
btTransform Trans = _RigidBody->getWorldTransform();

btVector3 Forward;  // ???
btVector3 Right;    // ???
btVector3 Up;       // ???

_RigidBody->activate(true);
//
//  Move forward/backward
_RigidBody->applyCentralForce(Forward * 5);
_RigidBody->applyCentralForce(-Forward * 5);
//
//  Jump
_RigidBody->applyCentralForce(Up * 5);
//
//  Move left/right
_RigidBody->applyCentralForce(Right * 5);
_RigidBody->applyCentralForce(-Right * 5);
```

I also have a GLM model matrix which is essentially a copy of the bullet transformation matrix inside a `glm::mat4` which I could use here instead and convert the resulting vector over to bullet but would much rather stay in bullet land for the entirety of this part.

Comment: I don't know the specification of type `btVector3`, but I would imagine that `bt3Vector3 Forward {1,0,0};` should work (assuming, the x-direction is your forward direction.)

Comment: The issue is after the object has been in the world for some time, and has been interacting with other objects, the forward direction wont be as simple as x+1 or z+1. It needs to be relative to the objects current rotation. Information which is contained within the btTransform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always say explicitly, what library you are using. I assume, you use [this](https://pybullet.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtTransform.html).

The `operator()` gives you the image of a vector under the transformation, so I assume, that the following does what you want:

`btVector3 Forward = Trans(btVector3{1,0,0});`

Comment: This will not work as after the physics object is rotated, x+1 will no longer be it's forward direction. The forward direction must be extracted out of it's current World Transformation which takes into account the objects current rotation.

Comment: @KKlouzal I am aware of that. Now assume `Trans` is a rotation about 90° around the z-axis, so `(1,0,0)` becomes `(0,1,0)`, now the forward direction should be `(0,1,0)` (or do I missunderstand you?). But this is exactly the ouput of `Trans(btVector3{1,0,0});`, since it just applies the rotation. In other words: The new forward is the image of the old forward under the transformation and `Trans(btVector3{1,0,0});` applies the transformation on the old forward.

Comment: I'm sorry I was half alseep replying last night. This works exactly as intended.